# How to evaluate the line integral?

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus

[image]

I've solved part (a) and (b), but I'm unsure about part (c).

My attempt is:

$\int_C f(x,y,z)ds$ = $\int_0^4 ((2t*\frac{4}{3}t^{3/2}*\frac{1}{2}t^2$)(t+2) = $\frac{2}{13}4^{3/2} + \frac{8}{33} 4^{11/2}$

But I'm not sure I'm on the right track at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**

You are asked to evaluate (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_integral)

$$\int_0^4 (f\circ r)(t)\cdot |r'(t)| dt=\int_0^4 \frac12 t^2 \sqrt{t^2+4t+4}dt=\int_0^4 \frac12 t^2 (t+2)dt.$$

Comment: Why does (f∘r)(t) only come to (1/2)t^2?

Comment: Since $f(x,y,z)=z$ you have that $f(\mbox{anything},\mbox{anything},1/2t^2)=1/2t^2.$ Note that $f$ doesn't depend on $x,y.$

Comment: Ok thanks, that makes sense :)

Comment: You're welcome.

Comment: So would that make the answer 53.33?

Comment: I have obtained the same result. In my opinion it is correct.